# how to draw a dated graph using D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

Hi all i am trying to add dates in the d3.js how can i achieve this i am new to d3.js when i try add integers instead of date in the X-axis it is working good ..
How to declare date and assign them
I am here by attaching the JS and HTML file 
thanks in advance:)

```
 InitChart();

 function InitChart() {

 /*var lineData = [{
 'x': 1,
 'y': 5
  }, {
 'x': 20,
 'y': 20
 }, {
 'x': 40,
 'y': 10
  }, {
'x': 60,
'y': 40
  }, {
  'x': 80,
  'y': 5
 }, {
  'x': 100,
 'y': 60
 }];*/
var lineData=[{"y": 0.8076999999999999, "x": "2016-01-08 03:01:19.418110"}, {"y": 0.692666666666667, "x": "2016-01-08 05:10:19.838509"}, {"y": 0.5674333333333333, "x": "2016-01-08 09:54:13.022163"}]

var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
WIDTH = 1000,
HEIGHT = 500,
MARGINS = {
  top: 20,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 20,
  left: 50
},
xRange = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([d3.min(lineData, function (d) {
    return d.x;
  }),
  d3.max(lineData, function (d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  ]),

  yRange = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top,          MARGINS.bottom]).domain([d3.min(lineData, function (d) {
    return d.y;
  }),
  d3.max(lineData, function (d) {
    return d.y;
  })
]),

xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(xRange)
  .tickSize(5)
  .tickSubdivide(true),

yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(yRange)
  .tickSize(5)
  .orient("left")
  .tickSubdivide(true);


 vis.append("svg:g")
.attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
.call(xAxis);

 vis.append("svg:g")
.attr("class", "y axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
.call(yAxis);

var lineFunc = d3.svg.line()
.x(function (d) {
  return xRange(d.x);
})
.y(function (d) {
return yRange(d.y);
})
.interpolate('linear');

vis.append("svg:path")
.attr("d", lineFunc(lineData))
.attr("stroke", "blue")
.attr("stroke-width", 2)
.attr("fill", "none");

  }
```

and here is the HTML

```
enter code here
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html >
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title> D3 trial </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
   <body>
   <svg id="visualisation" width="400" height="500"></svg>
   <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'>     </script>
  <script src='http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js'></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://hstefanski.wordpress.com/2015/06/28/creating-a-chart-with-d3-and-typescript-part-2), the example uses TypeScripit, but the concepts are the same. You basically need to use `d3.time.scale()` instead of `d3.scale.linear()`. You also need to parse your dates. Updated xRange should look like:

`xRange = d3.time.scale().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain(d3.extent(lineData, function (d) {
    return new Date(d.x);
  }))`

I used the `extent` function instead of `d3.min` and `d3.max`, which has the same effect but with shorter notation.

Comment: Can we also use seconds as I mentioned in my data set?? @Hugues ??

Comment: Sure. Have a look at the [time formatting](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting) possibilities, and the way to use it to [format ticks](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#tickFormat)

Comment: Yea Hugues I will try and  will tell u as soon as I try thanks :)

Comment: can u please help me with the syntax i am unable to make it :| here is the fiddle  
https://jsfiddle.net/Goutham_Pratapa/c6jf5yg0/

Comment: I updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c6jf5yg0/6/), it seems to work now. I configured the xRange as I mentionned in my answer, and removed `d3.max` which is now useless (this drew the axis). I then appended `.tickFormat(d3.time.format('%X'))` on the xAxis (and not on the scale - my mistake). This led to formatting the x axis as HH:MM:ss. I finally changed `.x(function (d) {    return xRange(new Date(d.x));  })` in `lineFunc` for dates to be used at display.

Comment: Sure, my comment was sent too fast

Comment: See my comment above, I described what I did and pointed to the working url

Comment: if i want to add date also to the graph what should i do??

Comment: change the `'%X'` in `d3.time.format('%X')` by something that suits your, e.g. `d3.time.format('%x %X')` will display date and time. This is where using the [d3 time formats](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting) come in handy :-)